# Android Video Editor API

Tags: android, android-video-player

I have a problem using Andoid's Video Editor project. I have cloned it from **Codeaurora.org** "platform/packages/apps/VideoEditor.git", but it requires another "VideoEditor API" subproject. Where can I find it? Does it use libvideoeditor library "platform/frameworks/media/libvideoeditor.git"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I was curious as well so I decided to take a look.

It looks like the code necessary to compile the project is in the Android framework tree. It can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/kitkat-release/media/java/android/media/videoeditor). I then made an Android library project with the source code in this directory. There was an error with a heap dump function that I just commented out and it compiles and runs fine on my Acer Iconia A100 with ICS which actually already has the Movie Studio app on it.

Comment: I just check your answer but a link that you have specified it broken can you share video editor if you have.

Comment: @Herry I just updated the URL. Looks like it was removed sometime during the Lollipop release so I pointed it specifically to the Kitkat release instead of master.