# Android Project Missing "VideoEditor API"

Tags: android, video

Here is my Problem

Project 'CyanogenMod-android_packages_apps_VideoEditor-6a89cf8' is missing required Java project: 'VideoEditor API' SickProgramming-android_packages_apps_VideoEditor-6a89cf8

I'm trying to make a video editor app. Found some sources from 'github'.
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_VideoEditor
I imported in to my workspace!!

I found this project missing error. I tried to find "VideoEditor API" and found "Android_Framework_base" which is this.
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base

I found source from framework (media/java/android/media/videoeditor)

But I have no idea to import this framework as "java project" so I can connect build_path for "apps_videoeditor"!!!

Thank You

Comment: Possible helpfull answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11199055/1683141